# Hibernate: optimal way for removing items from IndexColumn collection

Tags: java, hibernate

There're two tables `Transaction` and `TxTargets` their entities look like the following:

Transaction.java:

```
@Entity
public class Transaction {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private BigDecimal amount;

    @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tx_id")
    @IndexColumn(name="idx")
    private List<TxTargets> txTargets;
}
```

TxTargets.java

```
@Entity
public class TransactionAllocation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private TargetType type;

    private BigDecimal amount;
}
```

I need to remove TxTarget objects with 0 values from the collection where there're more than one element with the same tx_id. I cannot remove them straight from TxTarget because of the OneToMany relation and @IndexColumn.

In order to understand how the data may look, here is an example of it:

```
Transaction:
id|amount|txTargets
1  200    [1,2]
2  100    [3]
3  300    [4,5,6]

TxTargets
id|type|amount|idx|tx_id
1  tp1  200    0   1
2  tp1  0      1   1
3  tp2  100    0   2
4  tp2  150    0   3
5  tp2  0      1   3
6  tp2  150    2   3

TxTargets with ids 2 and 5 are expected to be deleted.
```

At the moment I remove them the following way:

1) Retrieve ids of all the TxTarget entities with 0 values with "having count(tx_id) > 1".

2) Retrieve all the Transaction entities which have TxTargets from (1).

3) Remove TxTarget objects from the collection according to the id list from (1)

4) Persist Transaction entity.

This way it works correctly, but I think it lacks performance (several collection iterations, at least) and has in general redundant actions.

I'd like to know are there better approaches for removing such entites and what are they?

Comment: Having a unidirectional association with just the OneToMany is already a performance problem. Anyway i would do 
the same query for retrieving the entities but instead of selecting them i'd issue a bulk delete and avoid the persistence context in this case

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/batch-direct.html